# problem in Retrieving Fingerprint template

Tags: c#

I am using digital persona and One Touch SDK, I managed to saved the Fingerprint Template to the database but the real Problem is i dont know how to retrieve and match the Fingerprint....

Code for saving Template.

```
private void saveprints(Byte[] array)
{
    conn = new SqlConnection(constring);
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Finger (Fingerprint)values(@img)", conn);


        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@img", array));
        if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}



private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Image Properties
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(picProfile.Image);

    MemoryStream fingerData = new MemoryStream();
    Template.Serialize(fingerData);
    fingerData.Position = 0;
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fingerData);
    Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fingerData.Length);


    bmpImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    byte[] data = ms.GetBuffer();

    if (prints.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (byte[] b in prints) {
            saveprints(b);
        }
    }
    else {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Scan your Finger", "Fingerprint Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    //if the texbox field is blank
    if (txtIDnum.Text == "" || txtFullname.Text == "" || txtContactNumber.Text == "" || txtCourseYear.Text == "" || txtDateregister.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Specify the Textbox Field!", "Information Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    else
    {
        //database code here
        using (conn = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            conn.Open();
            bool idCheck = false;
            //check if the ID is already in used
            using(cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from [student] where ID=@id",conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", txtIDnum.Text);
                idCheck = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
            }
            if (idCheck)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The ID '" + txtIDnum.Text + "' is Already used by Another User!, Enter New ID or Delete in the Student Data", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else {
                using(cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [student] values (@ID,@FN,@CY,@CN,@DR,@IMG,@FINGER)",conn))
                 {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID",txtIDnum.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FN", txtFullname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CY", txtCourseYear.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CN", txtContactNumber.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DR", txtDateregister.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FINGER", bytes);
                    //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IMG", save()));
                    SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@IMG", SqlDbType.Image);
                    p.Value = data;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    MessageBox.Show("Data Successfully Saved to Database", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
            conn.Close();

        }
```

Is there anyone know how to Retrieve and match fingerprint from database??? Please Help!

Comment: look at this manual => https://www.crossmatch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/UareU-SDK-Developer-Guide.pdf

Comment: sir  I think its different SDk. Its Crossmatch SDK maybe.  do you have example source code?

Comment: Is you have any technical specification manual then you will get what you want from it.

Comment: there no tutorial in saving template to the database in My manual. they save the template using fpt Fle. is saved in the Memory not in the database. -->http://www.warf.com/download/5744_9677_One%20Touch%20for%20Windows%20SDK%20.NET%20Developer%20Guide.pdf

Comment: this is how they saved the file --> `private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
   save.Filter = "Fingerprint Template File (*.fpt)|*.fpt";
   if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(save.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
     Template.Serialize(fs);
    }
   }
  }`

Comment: try to search is there any `Template.Deserialize()` method available or not?